# how to reference a session variable within a file outside of Controller, Model or View?

Tags: phalcon

I set a `session` variable inside a controller :

```
$this->session->set("navig_param",$livc_code);
```

Now I want to test if that session variable is not empty inside a php file outside of the Controller domain, Model domain and View domain. In fact this file is in a particular folder named **lib** at the same level as controllers, models and views. So how to test the session variable in this php file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also access your session data ( statically ) via

```
$session = Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('session');
$navigParam = $session->get('navig_param');
```

or oneliner:

```
$navigParam = Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('session')->get('navig_param');
```

reference : [phalcon static DI](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#accessing-the-di-in-a-static-way)

Answer (score 3):

```
$di=\Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
$session=$di->getSession();
if($session->has("navig_param"))
{
    $navig_param=$session->get("navig_param");
    //do something with it like flash it:
    $di->getFlash()->success('navig_param is: '.$navig_param);

}
```

Comment: what does flashing mean when we talk about phalcon session variable ?

Comment: Flash, in the context of Phalcon, does not refer to the video player, it refers to a service which makes it easy to output messages to the browser when you want to tell the user something. https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html
It is a useful debugging tool, much like `alert` in JavaScript. But you'll need to call `$this->flash->output();` from your view to output its contents, usually placed in your index.phtml file. It keeps a collection, meaning an array, of all messages you wish to flash as they pile up.

Comment: In the screenshot here there is two calls to flash for Phalcon's INVO demo application: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/_images/invo-2.png
One is an error message in red, the other is a notice message in blue.

Comment: It is also worth noting, as the top section in that link mentions, there's two adapters for using flash. There's flash direct and flash session. "Directly outputs the messages passed to the flasher" vs "Temporarily stores the messages in session, then messages can be printed in the next request". Which to use depends on how your application works. I prefer flash session, though, since it keeps the data active between redirects such as when applying the Post/Redirect/Get technique to prevent duplicate data submissions if the user reloads their page.

Answer (score 2):

As session is a service you only need an access to DI container:

```
$navigParam = $di->get('session')->get('navig_param');
```

Alternatively you can always use `$_SESSION` super global:

```
$navigParam = $_SESSION['navig_param'];
```

To get `$di` you can use: `$di = DI::getDefault();`

Comment: how to declare ( create ) this `$di` ?